# quasi ideal in semigroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, semigroups

I am new in semigroup theory and I have an problem related to quasi ideals. I am trying to solve the following problem

> **Problem:**
>   For a semigroup $S$, the following are equivalent
>
> 1. $S$ is regular
> 2. $A=ASA$ for every quasi ideal $A$

My approach for $1\implies 2$

Consider $a\in A$ since $S$ is regular so there exist $x\in S$ such that $a=axa$ so $A\subseteq ASA$

But I am not able to prove  $ASA\subseteq A$

Any help in this regard

EDIT. According to Clifford and Preston (*The algebraic theory of semigroups*, Volume I, p. 85), a subset $A$ of $S$ is a *quasi-ideal* if $AS \cap SA \subseteq A$.

Comment: Well, for starters, you are supposed to prove that $ASA\subseteq A$, not that $SAS\subseteq A$.

Comment: Note that $asa=(as)a = a(sa)\in SA\cap AS$.

Comment: oh yes,my mistake

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks! i get it

Comment: Could you please give the definition of a *quasi ideal* of a semigroup?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a quasi-ideal of $S$. Since $SA \subseteq S$ and $AS \subseteq S$, one gets $ASA \subseteq AS \cap SA \subseteq A$.